# Can't upload image in django use MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was trying to upload a image but I have been searching in google but I can not find a solution.
The problem is that it does not upload the image and in the field the database is saved null. 
Anyone help me to find a solution the problem.
I use django 1.10 and Linux.

Note :English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part

Note that If I can upload the image from within Django admin

## settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/imagenes/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from apps.almacen.categoria.models import Categoria
# Create your models here.
class Articulo(models.Model):
    idarticulo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigo= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stock= models.IntegerField()
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=512)
    imagen=models.FileField(upload_to = 'articulos/',null=True,blank=True)
    estado=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    idcategoria= models.ForeignKey(Categoria,db_column='idcategoria',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
                return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from apps.almacen.articulo.models import Articulo

class ArticuloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Articulo
        fields = [
            'idarticulo',
            'nombre',
            'codigo',
            'descripcion',
            'idcategoria',
            'stock',
            'imagen',

        ]
        labels = {
            'idarticulo':'Articulo',
            'nombre':'Nombre',
            'codigo':'Codigo',
            'descripcion':'Descripción',
            'idcategoria':'Categoria',
            'stock':'Stock',
            'imagen':'Imagen',

        }
        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Digite el nombre'}),
            'codigo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Digite el código'}),
            'idcategoria': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'stock': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Digite el stock'}),
            'descripcion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Digite la Descripción'}),
            'imagen': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

## Views.py

```
class ArticuloCreate(CreateView):
    model= Articulo
    form_class= ArticuloForm
    template_name='almacen/articulo/articulo_form.html'
    success_url= reverse_lazy('almacen_art:articulo_listar')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            articulos = form.save(commit=False)
            articulos.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

## articulo.html

```
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="image">Imagen</label>
                                    {{form.imagen}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                 </div>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: what's the error you're seeing?

Comment: This question is in danger of being closed. You need to provide a minimum example and probably include the error message.

Comment: @Falle The problem is that it does not upload the image and in the filed the database is saved null

Comment: @cwallenpoole Thanks, I added the problem in the ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the form on your `post` method but you're not binding your file to the new form, the docs clearly state that you need to do so:
[Binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form):

> Secondly, when you use the form, you need to bind the file data. File data is handled separately to normal form data, so when your form
>   contains a FileField and ImageField, you will need to specify a second
>   argument when you bind your form.

So your line

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST)
```

should become

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Also i think that your whole `post` method is unnecessary, you're just replicating the default behavior for the `CreateView`.
One other thing, having your media files located in the static files directory will make your `collectstatic` command run through all your uploaded files every time you make a change to your static files, you'll have way longer waiting time on that command and duplicate uploads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved it thanks at your advice.